# Cannot resolve resource Item winform resource file

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, resources, multilingual

This is the code for multilanguage:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsMultiLanguage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ResourceManager m_resourceManger;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            m_resourceManger = new ResourceManager("WindowsFormsMultiLanguage.Localization", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            // Init UICulture to CurrentCulture
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            // Init Controls
            UpdateUIControls();
        }



        private void UpdateUIControls()
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_resourceManger != null)
                {

                    this.label1.Text = m_resourceManger.GetString("test1");
                    this.label2.Text = m_resourceManger.GetString("test2");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
        private void OnLanguageChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
            string culture = string.Empty;

            switch (radioButton.Text)
            {

                case "French - France (fr-FR)":
                    culture = "fr-FR";
                    break;

                case "U.S. English (en-US)":
                    culture = "en-US";
                    break;

            }

            // This is used for the language of the user interface
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
        }

    }


}
```

I'm getting a error message, cannot resolve resource item test&, test2 at this point:
`this.label1.Text = m_resourceManger.GetString("test1");
this.label2.Text = m_resourceManger.GetString("test2");`

I have added 2 reource files 1 for english and 2nd for french, I don't know what is the mistake..

![enter image description here][1]
![enter image description here][2]

Comment: You mentioned test&. Is that a typo?

Comment: No, it's `test1 & test2`

Comment: Typo stands for [typographical error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typo).

Comment: yes..i got it. I didn't do any typing error. Could you please tell me where is the error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that resource `Localization` is not in namespace `Localization`, and so the parameter `"Localization.Localization"` for `ResourceManager` constructor is wrong. I'm just guessing here, because there is not enough information to find the problem.

EDIT: I downloaded the project, downgraded it to Visual Studio 2008 that I use (changed number 11 to 10 in .sln and 4.0 to 3.5 in two places in .csproj), and removed a reference to a component Microsoft.CSharp. The project was built and I ran it and there were no errors. Function `UpdateUIControls` was called only once in the beginning, but not when I changed the language. I copied two main lines from `UpdateUIControls` to the end of `OnLanguageChange` and after that texts were changing when I changed the language.

So, I don't see any problem. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I have updated complete code. please check it out. thank you.

Comment: The code appears to be okay, but so did previous code. I have no way of verifying the correctness of the code. Do you still have the problem, after changing the string?

Comment: Yes, I'm still having the same problem here, `this.label1.Text = m_resourceManger.GetString("test1"); this.label2.Text = m_resourceManger.GetString("test2");` error message `cannot resolve resource item`

Comment: In order to find the solution I would have to see more, but I don't know what exactly. The easiest way to resolve this is that you upload somewhere the complete project with all relevant files, including .sln, .csproj, and all resource files, and give me the link. This is not regular help for StackOverflow, but I feel generous today.

Comment: Here is the skydrive link & it's public: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=8fe34cb77340caa9&id=8FE34CB77340CAA9!150   you can download...thank u very much

Comment: For me it's changing during the form load and then for the first click and after that the text is not changing...! Is it possible to share the project?? Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18961/discussion-between-dialecticus-and-linguini)

Comment: "stackoverflow.com" is allowed, but "chat.stackoverflow.com" is not? Interesting. Ask them to change the policy. Anyway I don't understand the question. You shared the project, and I downloaded it, so it is possible to share the project. You just did it.